# How to put a long-term lock on a row in a MySQL InnoDB Table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I've searched this for a while and couldn't find much.

Is it possible to lock individual rows manually on an InnoDB table in MySQL?

Basically we have a table where some records are processed and should no longer be edited. They need to be kept in the state they're currently in, but still be readily accessible in terms of reading the data.

We already have a "locked" column which is 0 or 1, but **somehow**, it's being edited when it shouldn't be. Rather than relying on the code to behave nicely, we were wanting to put a hard lock on it at a MySQL level, so these **can't** be changed, even if our PHP code tries to somewhere.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

To do this correctly, use application partitioning such that your application stores active data in one table and historical data in another, and use permissions to specify that your application can read one table and read/write on another.

Alternatively, add an access layer so that you read through views and write through stored procedures, and have the SP control whether a row can be written based on the field value.

Either way you can't do this with MySQL natively without writing some code somewhere

Comment: Damn :( looks like that idea's going out the window then! Thanks for the definitive answer.